# Using .txt into a list kinda

Tags: python

hi guys just needing so help with reading .txt into a list I think what I've got so far is

```
r = open('RegsInList.txt','r')

rr =(r.readlines())
#print(rr)
```

this works it imports the text file and reads it I need it to read into a list. So I can put it under list obj and then it to split it up

```
listobj = ['AV46 WAD','WD40 ASD','BG65 KYS','WA48 DFT','GH09 DEG']
var1, var2, var3,var4 ,var5 = listobj
print(var1)
print(var2)
print(var3)
print(var4)
print(var5)
```

my .txt looks like,

```
'AV46 WAD','WD40 ASD','BG65 KYS','WA48 DFT','GH09 DEG'
```

thanks for the help if you can give

edited:

```
time1list = open('time1.txt','r')
time1 =(time1list.readlines())
#print(regs)

listobj = time1[0].replace("'", '').split(',')
time11, time12, time13,time14 ,time15 = listobj
print(time11)
print(time12)
print(time13)
print(time14)
print(time15)
```

gives me error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/GameDevelopment/Desktop/Desktop/Python/AvgSpeed/Times/Time1Split.py", line 2, in 
    time1 =(time1list.readlines())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Is your file only having one line of text i.e `'AV46 WAD','WD40 ASD','BG65 KYS','WA48 DFT','GH09 DEG' `? Will it always have one line or is there a possibility of text being distributed in various lines?

Comment: I think It should just have 1 line maybe just 5 Items etc

Comment: What you are doing is fine, what do u want to change. readlines() already returns a list/generator from which you can extract details.

Comment: You may just do `listobj = rr[0].replace("'", '').split(',')`

Comment: this looks like a job for the `csv` module

Comment: when I change listobj to rr it gives me errors because I'm bringing it from a .txt I think ? also thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @AdamMartin It shouldn't give the error if your `rr` is holding the value of `rr = r.readlines()`

Comment: csv model Ive never used or heard of that ?

Comment: ill see whats the error is giving me 2s

Comment: r = open('RegsInList.txt','r')

    rr =(r.readlines())
    #print(rr)

    listobj = rr
    var1, var2, var3,var4 ,var5 = listobj
    print(var1)
    print(var2)
    print(var3)
    print(var4)
    print(var5)
this is what I've got and it giving me the error

Comment: that didn't work how would I do that ? for code again ?

Comment: @AdamMartin In this I can not see the code line I mentioned :) Place `listobj = rr[0].replace("'", '').split(',')` after the `rr = r.readlines()` line. *PS: Don not forget to remove `listobj = rr`*

Comment: thanks you are the man If I need anymore help I'm comment thank you so so much

Comment: whats wrong with the bit I put under edited?

Answer (score 0):

You may read this .txt into a list and print it like this:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as infile:
    content = [i.strip("'") for i in infile.read().split(",")]
for i in content:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to achieve your objective:

1. Read the file
2. Split item in each line by ','
3. Add each item to a list

Sample code:

```
    with open("input.txt","r")  as fp:
        lines = fp.readline()

    for line in lines:
         listobj = line.split(",")

    for item in listobj:
         print(item)
```